# How to invalid or blacklist JWT token in larvel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, jwt

How to logged out JWT token  or black list token in laravel 5.4 i am using jwt package like `composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source` when i call the logout function from postmen to my auth controller it successfully logged out but old token still valid for use how can i destroy the jwt token in my loggout method.
Any body have an idea to logged out jwt token thanks in advance.Every thing is working except logout.

laravel version 5.4

this is the route

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function()
{
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
});
```

This is method for logged out

```
 public function logout()
    {
       $token = JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
       if($token)
       {
          return response()->json([
               'message' => 'User logged out successfully!'
          ], 200);
        } 
        else 
        {
           return response()->json([
               'message' => 'Failed to logout user. Try again.'
            ], 500);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logout in JWT does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797393/logout-in-jwt-does-not-work)

Comment: In the response request to delete the cookie as well `->withCookie(\Cookie::forget('jwt_token'));`

Comment: where i do this